# apache2 not using directory specified in site-available/joomla.conf

Tags: apache, ubuntu, joomla, webserver

I am running a ubuntu server.
I installed apache according to this site:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Joomla
I then created a file called `joomla.conf` in the `/etc/apache2/sites-available` directory. It is the same as the default configuration except I changed the `DocumentRoot` line to `DocumentRoot /var/www/joomla`. That is the directory where my joomla site is.
Some websites were saying to change the `<Directory>` directive but my default file didn't have one so I added it, like this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/joomla">
</Directory>
```

I ran `a2dissite 000-default` and `a2ensite joomla.conf`. 
`/var/www/` originally contained a `html` directory.  Even with the above steps having been performed, apache still loads from `/var/www/html/index.html`. I obviously haven't edited the right file or something, help is appreciated.
Another curious thing, I don't have an `/etc/httpd` directory, or a `httpd.conf` file in my apache directory. I don't know if I need that or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had edited the files in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` which was over-riding any changes made is `sites-available/`. The `sites-enabled` directory is only meant to contain symlinks to the files in `sites-available`.
To fix it I first removed the non-symlink files from `sites-enabled` then removed and and re-added the configuration with the following commands:

```
$ sudo a2dissite joomla
$ sudo a2ensite joomla
```

(joomla.conf is the name of my config file)
Then I restarted the server with `sudo service apache2 reload`.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a leading slash in your  directive:

```
<Directory "var/www/joomla">
</Directory>
```

Instead, it should be

```
<Directory "/var/www/joomla">
</Directory>
```

Change this, disable/enable joomla.conf and restart your apache server.

If there are problems after fixing this - the full joomla.conf listing could help.

Instead of /etc/httpd in Ubuntu you have /etc/apache2. Instead of httpd.conf you have apache2.conf as a main configuration file. This is specific for Ubuntu, feels convenient after being used to it.